# automatically install missing cookbooks?

Tags: chef-infra, chefdk

When I upload some cookbooks to my Chef Server it says that I'm missing cookbooks. It allows me to upload the cookbook to the server doesn't show it in my server I'm assuming because it's missing some of the cookbooks it depends on. is there a way to automatically install the cookbooks that it depends on when I select a cookbook to upload? So if I upload MongoDB to my chef server it will automatically bring all of its dependencies with it so I don't have to go through and upload each one manually.

Answer (score 2):

This is what Berkshelf is for. It handles finding the dependencies, pulling them down locally (`berks install`), and then pushing them up to the Chef Server (`berks upload`). The new Policyfile workflow also handles this for you.

Comment: Do I install Berkshelf on my workstation? And then use Berkshelf in conjunction with the Chefdk to achieve this functionality.